# Run python scripts through php on an android app

Tags: android

I am new to all of this but 
I'm trying a bit of home automation through my raspberry pi, I have a local web server which I can use to turn the lights on and off, here's the php code:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>


<?php
if (isset($_POST['ON']))
  {
exec("sudo python /home/pi/turnOn.py");
  }
if (isset($_POST['OFF']))
 {
  exec("sudo python /home/pi/turnOff.py");
 }
?>
<form method="post">
<button name="ON">ON</button>&nbsp;
<button name="OFF">OFF</button><br>



</form>
</html>
```

Now, I have made two buttons in my android app

```
<Button
    android:layout_below="@+id/t1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/b1"
    android:text="ON"
    android:onClick="switchOn"/>
<Button
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/t1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/b2"
    android:text="OFF"
    android:onClick="switchOff"/>
```

I'm not sure of this but after a bit of reading I tried this...
So, this is the block of Java code I've tried to connect to my local server on the raspberry pi

```
public void Connect(View view){
    String url="http://192.168.1.3/index.php";
    DefaultHttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet get=new HttpGet(url);
    try
    {
        HttpResponse response=client.execute(get);
        HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
        String result= EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I want to make the buttons (in android) so that when pressed 'ON' in the android app it does the same thing it does on the php document when we press 'ON' their. What java method should I write to achieve this